# HttpClient 401 Unauthorized after PostAsync (Bearer Auth)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, api

I'm new at this never use REST API before I just stuck on the post I don't know how to get the code 200 in the PostAsync. What I doing wrong or what I missing?....

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "IndividualId,SolicitantDataView,TerminalId,OGPCorrelationID,OGPATGNumber,Source,UserId,SendByEmail")] RequestViewModel requestViewModel)
    {
        var token = await GetToken();
        RequestModel requestModel = new RequestModel(requestViewModel);
        string Baseurl = "https://exampleapiservice.com/api";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);
            var content2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
           {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("IndividualId", requestViewModel.IndividualId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OGPATGNumber", requestViewModel.OGPATGNumber),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OGPCorrelationID", requestViewModel.OGPCorrelationID),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Source", requestViewModel.Source),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserId", requestViewModel.UserId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TerminalId", requestViewModel.TerminalId.ToString()),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SendByEmail", requestViewModel.SendByEmail.ToString()),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.Name),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MiddleInitial", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.MiddleInitial),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LastName", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.LastName),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LastName2", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.LastName2),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SSN", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.SSN),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("BirthDate", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.BirthDate.ToString()),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("EmailAddress", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.EmailAddress),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DriverLicense", requestViewModel.SolicitantDataView.DriverLicense)

    });
            var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content2);
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
            var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
            byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");



            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("/api/getcertification ", byteContent);

}
        return View(requestModel);
    }
```

This is the parameters I need to fill. I'm trying to test in Postman but I never use that app. How is the correct way to add those parameters in Postman??

```
{

"SolicitantData": null,

"DemographicalData": {

"Name": "Nombre",

"MiddleInitial": "I",

"LastName": "Apellido Paterno",

"LastName2": "Apellido Materno",

"NickName": "",

"SSN": "123456789",

"BirthDate": "19xx-xx-xx",

"EmailAddress": "email@somedomain.com",

"DriverLicense": "",

"DeathDate": "",

"Addresses": [],

"PhoneNumbers": []
```

}

Comment: you'll have to figure out why the service is returning that.

Comment: Are you actually leaving `Baseurl` as just 'https://'? Or are you putting a real URL in there?

Comment: @Jonathan your code incomplete, where is actual ActionResult you are returning asyncronously?

Comment: Are you able to make a valid request with another tool (Postman, SoapUI, etc...)

Comment: @ArturMustafin I just post the part that give me the error:  HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync(" ", byteContent); and Jonathan that BaseUrl is a example I have the correct one.

Comment: @Jonathan Padilla I do not see that you code is returning anything, will you provide complete method implementation where it is clear where are you returning actual value?

Comment: @ArturMustafin Is just returning  a the model(requestModel) but the debug not reach the return cuz on the Post Async crash.

Comment: Is the user getting into the method? if not, do you have an HttpPost attribute on the controller method?

Comment: @Noel Yes I do.

Comment: @JonathanPadilla What dotnet framework you are using .net, .net core?

Comment: @ArturMustafin .net

Comment: @JonathanPadilla it seems authentication issue it mean you have an issue in token generation try the same request on any external tool and check how you generate the token i think its wrong

Comment: @AhmedYousif I try that and the token is successfully provide.

Comment: @JonathanPadilla which auth type do you use?

Comment: @AhmedYousif Bearer.

Comment: can you show me example of first 25 char of the token

Comment: The token expire each 10min: SF35FmM515OM9Yp7LysaLRh5Qzx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to include authentication type before the token so you need to 
replace this line of the code to include auth type e.g. `Bearer`

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);
```

with

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
```

Comment: I actually add a example of the parameters I need to fill and I think I'm missing something else in the code on the HttpClient part.

Comment: Yeah right now and now th var content2 =new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] throw me a object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: so you pass the first authorization issue?

Comment: Yes and I pass the Auth before and pass the content2 but now with this change I can't the FormUrlEncodedContent.

Comment: you have one of values in side posted data is null you have to debug it and handle it

Comment: so check this bug first to be able to check authentication issue

Comment: Ok I fix the issue now pass the line FormUrlEncodedContent pass and now I receive the code 500 internal server error. I want to test it on Postman to see is the url is working but I never use that tool and I don't know how to put the parameters in the correct way.

Comment: this is mean that url of api you use is wrong not found in server you call check this url

Comment: That's what I'm telling to my superior and he keep telling me that's the correct url... sigh. You know how to use Postman I want to test there  and confirm if the url is wrong?

Comment: I test it on Postman and is working fine the problem is on the code then. The way I'm passing the parameters.

Comment: how you set url in the code?and what is the actual url?

Comment: I put the entire code including the the example url.

Comment: I think you have to change baseurl to be https://exampleapiservice.com instead of https://exampleapiservice.com/api